# Microsoft C library _beginthreadex

Tags: c, winapi, windbg

I'm studying Windows System Programming 4th edition by Johnson M. Hart. Below is a snippet of source from one example that has stumped me in windbg. The snippet below creates a thread for each file on the command line. What I notice is the threads are not visible in windbag using ~ or ~~[TID]. However procexp and procmon show the threads.

Why are the threads not visible in windbg? If they are suppose be, how can I see them. I have set a breakpoint on the ###!_beginthreadex function. The breakpoint is triggered but upon step through the functionI don't see the thread.

```
for (iThrd = 0; iThrd < argc - 2; iThrd++) {

        /* Set: targv[1] to the pattern
            targv[2] to the input file
            targv[3] to the output file. */

    _tcscpy (gArg[iThrd].targv[1], argv[1]); /* Pattern. */
    _tcscpy (gArg[iThrd].targv[2], argv[iThrd + 2]); /* Search file. */

    if (GetTempFileName /* Temp file name */
            (".", "Gre", 0, gArg[iThrd].targv[3]) == 0)
        ReportError (_T ("Temp file failure."), 3, TRUE);

    /* Output file. */

    gArg[iThrd].argc = 4;

    /* Create a thread to execute the command line. */

    tHandle[iThrd] = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex (
            NULL, 0, ThGrep, &gArg[iThrd], 0, NULL);

    if (tHandle[iThrd] == 0)
        ReportError (_T ("ThreadCreate failed."), 4, TRUE);
}
```

Comment: Are the threads shortlived? Depending on your Difference Highlight Duration in ProcExp, they can remain visible for up to 9 seconds in ProcExp after they have completed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to see all your active threads in windbg,
but when they terminate, they are gone.
You can observe thread creation / deletion, by enable exception notify on these (sxn xx).

```
0:001> sxn ct
0:001> sxn et
0:001> g
Exit thread 1:2944, code 0
Create thread 1:2cbc
Create thread 2:2aec
Exit thread 2:2aec, code 0
Create thread 2:1a5c
```

Here I list threads still active:

```
0:002> ~  
   0  Id: 25c0.2d3c Suspend: 1 Teb: 7efdd000 Unfrozen
   1  Id: 25c0.2cbc Suspend: 1 Teb: 7efda000 Unfrozen "kgtDlgThread"
.  2  Id: 25c0.1a5c Suspend: 1 Teb: 7efd7000 Unfrozen
```

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about thread events I will try it and let you know

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Using the thread events I can now break on the thread creation and inspect the stack

Comment: also you can use a normal break (bp) at the thread start address, ThGrep in your case.